# Is there a "while" equivalent that can be used inside a parenthetical statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, shortcut

I often find JavScript shortcuts useful, such as replacing if/else statements like

```
if (a !== 0) {
  b = c;
} else {
  b = d;
}
```

with

```
b = a ? c : d;
```

or replacing for/next loops like

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  element = array[i];
  /* do something with element... */
}
```

with

```
array.forEach(element => { /* do something with element... */ });
```

I especially like that these and other similar shortcuts can be combined and used inside parenthetical statements, such as

```
array.forEach(e => (x += e ? a : b, e * x));
```

(works)

However, I haven't been able to find a shortcut or functional equivalent to the "while" statement that works inside parentheses. Is there such a thing?

I tried to use a normal while statement inside parentheses, but I got an error

```
array.forEach(e => (while (e.length > 160) { e.replace(' ', ''); }, e));
```

(doesn't work)

I know the above can be rewritten in a longer form, like so

```
array.forEach(e => {
  while (e.length > 160) {
     e.replace(' ', '');
  }
  return e;
});
```

(works)

But there are times I'd really prefer an inline shorthand equivalent to while, rather than the long version. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your "Longer form" example is exactly the same length as the "shorter" example, except for white-space formatting.  The only difference is using braces correctly instead of parens.

Comment: Your while loop may or may not ever end. If you pass in a string composed of 161+ non-space characters, you'll never leave the while loop. I'm not sure why you're looping it, anyway; replace will get all instance of the character in a single call. Also, it looks like you have a syntax error in your single-line version.

Comment: @SteveH. I think the point is that he wants to use the comma operator instead of a return statement

Comment: At best, you could [write some kind of function](https://jsfiddle.net/01ztg7wk/) which would be longer than what you have now since it would require a function for the predicate (`e.length > 160`) and one for the body of the loop. That is, if you want it to be completely generic. If JS had a macro system then you could pull off something shorter.

Comment: You might consider using something like [Sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/doc/1.0/tutorial.html) to write a macro for something like this.

Comment: The point of conditional expressions is to have a return value, not to be a shortcut for an if statement. And that's the reason why while loops have no expression equivalent: they don't have a return value. What you actually seem to be looking for is the array `reduce` method.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein - You're right. I was just trying to provide a simple example.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein *"replace will get all instance of the character in a single call"* – no. `'foo bar bog'.replace(' ', '') // => 'foobar bog'`

Comment: @naomik My mistake, though a regex with the g tag (`/ /g`) will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
const cutSpace = str => str.length > 160
  ? cutSpace(str.replace(' ', ''))
  : str

const trimmedStrings = array.map(cutSpace)
```

Comment: BTW Can anyone clarify if my example is a good candidate for proper tail call optimisation or should I negate predicate and call `cutSpace` in "else expression"?

Comment: It's a tail call regardless in which branch you put it.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I accepted this answer because it solved the problem with the least code (which is what I was looking for).

Comment: I accepted this answer because it solved the problem with the least code (which is what I was looking for).

However, because this isn't significantly shorter than the while loop I was trying to replace, I think the real answer is that the extremely short shortcut I was wondering about doesn't exist.

Comment: @DSchnellDavis the amount of talking you do about "shortcuts" causes me great pain.

Answer (score 2):

> I especially like that these and other similar shortcuts can be combined and used inside parenthetical statements, such as
>
> ```
> array.forEach(e => (x += e ? a : b, e * x));
> ```
>
> (works)

What? In what capacity does this code "work"? If I saw this code in review, I'd reject it immediately.

- External state mutation in a predicate?
- Inside a loop, nonetheless?
- Not to mention neither `a` nor `b` is used.
- Not to mention the parentheses and trailing `e * x` expression is completely thrown away, too... (?)

It's so bad it hurts.

> I tried to use a normal while statement inside parentheses, but I got an error
>
> ```
> array.forEach(e => (while (e.length > 160) { e.replace(' ', ''); }, e));
> ```
>
> (doesn't work)

Well it's a syntax error. You tried to use a **statement** where only **expressions** are allowed. Things like `if`, `for`, `while`, `do` are *statements*. You cannot put a statement in a `(...)` expression. Even if you *could* use a `while` expression here, the code still wouldn't *do* anything. Every computation is completely discarded

> I know the above can be rewritten in a longer form, like so
>
> ```
> array.forEach(e => {
>   while (e.length > 160) {
>      e.replace(' ', '');
>   }
>   return e;
> });
> ```
>
> (works)

"works"? How does this work? Syntactically it's OK, but it doesn't actually *do* anything.

- Strings are immutable so `String.prototype.replace` will not mutate `e` like I think you're imaging it does.
- `Array.prototype.forEach` ignores the return value in your iterator function
- `Array.prototype.forEach` has no return value of its own

---

I can only assume you mean to do something like this

```js
let input = [
  'a b c d e f g h',
  'i j k l m n o',
  'p q r s t u',
  'v w x y z'
]

input.forEach(e => {
  while (e.length > 9)
    e = e.replace(' ', '')
  console.log(e)
})

// abcdefg h
// ijklm n o
// pqr s t u
// v w x y z
```

Do you see the difference? I'm using `e = e.replace(...)` because `replace` does not mutate the input string in place. Also, my iterator is actually doing something with the value – `console.log`, dumb as it might be

It seems tho like you might be unaware of `Array.prototype.map`. Like `replace`, `map` will not mutate the original input – instead, a new value is returned. So this time we assign the return value of the map to a new variable, `output`, and log that when we're done

```js
let input = [
  'a b c d e f g h',
  'i j k l m n o',
  'p q r s t u',
  'v w x y z'
]

let output = input.map(e => {
  while (e.length > 9)
    e = e.replace(' ', '')
  return e
})

console.log(output)
// [
//   "abcdefg h",
//   "ijklm n o",
//   "pqr s t u",
//   "v w x y z"
// ]
```

Neither of these last two code snippets are *bad*. The first one has an I/O side effect (console.log in the forEach) but the second one is entirely pure and entirely functional. There's nothing wrong with *local* mutation and there's nothing wrong with using `while` in your programs, especially considering no JavaScript VM that I know of supports tail call optimisation - recursion is actually not the bees knees in the land of JS.

Comment: So I don't really provide the answer to your question, instead this answer explains your basically barking up the wrong tree. It's evident your main goal is to keep your code "short", anyway – which is a joke considering correct structure is far more important than clever syntax soup that appears in the code snippets in your question. There's nothing inherently wrong with `for` or `while` and you can maintain functional interfaces within your program even tho some functions may locally use such statements. TL:DR; don't try to get around these things, *especially* for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Thanks for putting my thoughts into written text :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be shorter, but it is functional:

```js
const array = [
  '       ',
  '      ',
  '     ',
  '    ',
  '   ',
  '  ',
  ' ',
  '',
];

const result = array.map(e => (f => (g => x => f(g(g))(x))(h => x => f(h(h))(x)))(f => e => e.length > 2 && f(e.replace(' ', '')) || e)(e) );

console.log( result );
```

I changed 160 to `2` and used `map` instead of `forEach` to make it easier to demonstrate.

Comment: Assigning to `e` isn't exactly functional either, is it?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, removing that assignment shorten's the code. I was just using that to demonstrate that the OP's longer version doesn't do anything since there is no assignment.

Answer (score -2):

If you're doing a single command in the loop, you can use a for loop;

```
array.forEach(e => for(; e.length > 160; e.replace(' ', ''));return e;})
```

Comment: So why was this voted down? It looks like it answers the question, and appears to be the most compact version so far.

Comment: Never mind - I figured it out. This is a potentially clever idea, but it doesn't work. When I tried to use this inside a parenthetical statement, I got an error, much like I got for the while statement.